# select query not workin

Tags: php, select

the problem was that in the config file was mysql so i change it to mysqli

but now i cant see the result in the select in the html area

1. this is the php script

   ```
   <?php 
   require 'config.php';

   $query = "SELECT cat_id, category FROM categories LIMIT 1"; 
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
   if(!$result){
       echo 'Query failed : '.mysqli_error();
       exit(0); 
   }  
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   //  mysql_fetch_assoc was the problem print_r($row);

   mysql_close($con);

   ?>
   ```
2. this is the html script

   ```
   <select name="cat_id"> </select>
   ```
3. this is thr error

   ```
   Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource
   given in /home/content/60/10533160/html/cms/in.php on line 5

   Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
   /home/content/60/10533160/html/cms/in.php on line 7  Query failed :
   ```

Comment: What will we do with that mate? should post your query here.... not only the error..

Comment: may be your getting connection error check all fields once mysqli_connections takes 4 params last one db name

Comment: Just look at the documentation for the thing, it should be immediately evident.

Comment: You are mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` commands.

Comment: Show code where connection to database is established

Comment: What's inside config.php? Apparently there is something wrong with the `$con` variable.

Comment: I was just going to ask about $con... c'mon mate, help me help you

Comment: and use all mysqli only

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you used `mysql` not `mysqli` for your connection.

maybe you should change that, as it says `mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is caused because mysqli_fetch_assoc() needs two parameters, a database name and parameter two to be the array you wish to fetch. 
Your code should be (presuming `$con` is the database connection):

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($con,$result);
```

Your second error is simply caused because `mysqli_error()` expects 1 parameter: The database connection, but you connected with `mysql.*`. Don't mix the two libraries. `mysqli` has many improvements over the original `mysql` extension, so it is recommended that you use `mysqli`.

Make sure to do some research on Google before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age)
VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This example is useful for you...

Comment: $con = mysql_connect("matancms.db.10533160.hostedresource.com","matancms","S888803%");
mysql_select_db("matancms");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: add a db name matancms as a last paramater for mysql_connect...and change mysql_connect to mysqli_connect..